# Java 2 dimensional array throwing out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new with arrays.

This program i have created is throwing an out of bounds error with every method inside of the BlueJays class.

To be honest, im not even sure if im searching through the array right. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

This is my main

```
public class Lab1 {

static final int NBPLAYERS = 11;
static final int NBMONTHS = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] month = {"April", "May","June", "July", "August","September"};
    String[] players = {"Colabello","Donaldson","Smoak","Martin","Goins","Encarnacion","Carrera","Tulowitzki","Pillar","Bautista","Travis"};
    double[][] battingAvg = {
                    {0,.368,.300,.224,.386,.268},
            {.319,.306,.269,.287,.324,.296},
            {.229,.310,.213,.191,.203,.262},
            {.197,.327,.239,.256,.138,.213},
            {.276,.236,.172,.240,.314,.279},
            {.205,.225,.303,.241,.407,.279},
            {0,.302,.282,.244,.333,.231},
            {0,0,0,.357,.214,.237},
            {.273,.181,365,.283,.240,.323},
            {.164,.295,.226,.219,.286,.293},
            {.325,.189,.313,.368,0,0}};

    double [][] onBase = {
                    {.417,.330,.286,.413,.362,.429},        
            {.370,.373,.322,.370,.408,.403},
            {.372,.333,.275,.283,.243,.324},
            {.367,.362,.329,.322,.263,.300},
            {.323,.278,.221,.286,.442,.347},
            {.258,.333,.382,.384,.460,.411},
            {0,.357,.333,.277,.333,.313},
            {0,0,0,.400,.325,.250},
            {.297,.237,.380,.323,.283,.363},
            {.325,.418,.388,.300,.370,.436},
            {.393,.246,.313,.421,0,0}};


    PlayerStats Player;

    BlueJays team = new BlueJays(NBPLAYERS, NBMONTHS);

    team.getHighestSingleMonthBattingAvg();

    team.getHighestOnBase(5);

    team.getLowestBattingAvg(6);

    team.getBestMonth("Bautista");

    team.getBestOverallRecord();

    team.getLowestOnBase();
}
}
```

This is my PlayerStats which has accessor/mutator methods.

```
class PlayerStats {

private String name;
private int month;
private double battAvg, onBase;


public PlayerStats(String name, int month, double battingAvg, double onBase2) {

    this.name = name;
    this.month = month;
    this.battAvg = battingAvg;
    this.onBase =  onBase2;

}

public String getName() {

    return name; 
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public int getMonth() {

    return month;
}

public void setMonth(int month) {

    this.month = month; 
}


public double getAvg() {

    return battAvg;
}

public double getOnBase() {

    return onBase;
}

public double getBoth() {

    return battAvg + onBase;
}

}
```

And this is the class where the 2d array is created.

```
class BlueJays {

int nbPlayers;
int nbMonths;
int j = 0;
int highestBattingAvg;
int highestBattingMonth;
String highestBattingPlayer;
int highestOnBase;
int lowestAvg;
String lowestAvgPlayer;
int highestOverall;
String highestOverallPlayer;
int lowestOnBase;
int lowestOnBaseMonth;
String highestOnBasePlayer;
double bestOverAllMonth;



public BlueJays(int nbplayers2, int nbmonths2) {
    this.nbPlayers = nbplayers2;
    this.nbMonths = nbmonths2;

}

    PlayerStats[][] stats = new PlayerStats[nbPlayers][nbMonths];

PlayerStats setPlayerStatsCell(PlayerStats player, int iPlayer, int iMonth) {
    return player;


}


PlayerStats getHighestSingleMonthBattingAvg() {

    while(j < nbMonths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
            stats[i][j].getAvg();


            if(highestBattingAvg < stats[i][j].getAvg()) {
                highestBattingMonth = stats[i][j].getMonth();
                highestBattingPlayer = stats[i][j].getName();

            }

            if (i == nbMonths) {
                j++;
                i = 0;

            }

            System.out.println("Highest average batting player for the month " + highestBattingMonth + " is " + highestBattingPlayer);

        }
    }


    return null;


}

PlayerStats getHighestOnBase(int month) {

    while(j < nbMonths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
            stats[i][month].getOnBase();

            if(highestOnBase < stats[i][month].getOnBase()) {

                highestOnBasePlayer =  stats[i][month].getName();
            }

            if (i == nbMonths) {
                j++;
                i = 0;

            }
            System.out.println("Highest average onBase player for the month " + month + highestOnBasePlayer);

        }
    }


    return null;

}


public PlayerStats getLowestBattingAvg(int month) {

    while(j < nbMonths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
            stats[i][month].getOnBase();

            if(lowestAvg > stats[i][month].getAvg()) {

                lowestAvgPlayer =  stats[i][month].getName();
            }

            if (i == nbMonths) {
                j++;
                i = 0;

            }

            System.out.println("Lowest average batting player for the month " + month + " is " + lowestAvgPlayer);

        }
    }
    return null;

}

   PlayerStats getBestMonth(String player) {

   while(j < nbMonths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
            stats[i][j].getBoth();

            if(bestOverAllMonth > stats[i][j].getAvg() && stats[i][j].getName().contains(player)) {


                 bestOverAllMonth =  stats[i][j].getBoth();


            }

            if (i == nbMonths) {
                j++;
                i = 0;

            }
            System.out.println("Best month for the player " + player + " is " + bestOverAllMonth);


        }
    }
    return null;






}

public String getBestOverallRecord() {

    while(j < nbMonths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
            stats[i][j].getBoth();

            if(highestOverall < stats[i][j].getBoth()) {

                highestOverallPlayer =  stats[i][j].getName();
            }

            if (i == nbMonths) {
                j++;
                i = 0;

            }

            System.out.println("Highest overall record is " + highestOverallPlayer);

        }
    }
    return null;



}



public PlayerStats getLowestOnBase() {

    while(j < nbMonths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
            stats[i][j].getOnBase();

            if(lowestOnBase > stats[i][j].getOnBase()) {

                double lowestOnBase =  stats[i][j].getOnBase();

                if(lowestOnBase > 0) {

                    lowestAvgPlayer = stats[i][j].getName();

                } else {

                    i++;
                }
            if (i == nbMonths) {
                j++;
                i = 0;

            }

        }
            System.out.println("Lowest On Base is  " + lowestOnBase);


    }



}
    return null;

}
}
```

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at BlueJays.getHighestSingleMonthBattingAvg(BlueJays.java:42)
at Lab1.main(JonathanRoy_Lab1.java:40)
```

Comment: post the exception as well

Comment: You are initializing the array before setting the values of nbPlayers & nbMonth, therefor the array size is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may lay here:

```
// ... lots of other stuff
public BlueJays(int nbplayers2, int nbmonths2) {
     this.nbPlayers = nbplayers2;
     this.nbMonths = nbmonths2;
}

PlayerStats[][] stats = new PlayerStats[nbPlayers][nbMonths];
```

If you initialize an instance of your `BlueJay`-class it will create the array before you set the values `nbPlayers` and `nbMonths`. So you'll have an array of the size 0 and 0.

To avoid this you have to do following:

```
// ... lots of other stuff
public BlueJays(int nbPlayers, int nbMonths) {
    this.nbPlayers = nbPlayers;
    this.nbMonths = nbMonths;
    // doesn't matter if you take the parameters or fields
    this.stats = new PlayerStats[nbPlayers][nbMonths];
}
```

Hope I helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exception is but here's what I got by scanning through your code.

1. You never reset `j` so most of your function calls won't make it past the first comparison.
2. The function call `team.getLowestBattingAvg(6);` uses the index 6, but since `nbMonths=6`, the highest index you can use is 5 (the indices go from 0 to 5 inclusive).

Comment: It happens on the first one, where J is zero.